# ResultSet is not for INSERT query? Error message: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String

Tags: java, jdbc

I think I got it wrong at the 'resultset'. My code for inserting data is :

```
ResultSet columns = statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Feedback (Username, Feedbacks) VALUES( '" + user + "','"+ msg +"')");
```

The compilation error is:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

[`Statement#executeUpdate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't return a `ResultSet`, but an `int` representing the affected rows. Fix it as follows.

```
int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Or if you aren't interested in the amount of affected rows, just ignore it.

```
statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

By the way, the compilation error at its own is weird. Aren't you looking at the wrong line? The error tells that you're trying to assign an `int` result to a `String`, but your code shows that you're trying to assign `int` result to a `ResultSet`.

---

That said and unrelated to your current problem, if `user` and `msg` are parts of user-controlled input, then this piece of code is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). I strongly recommend to replace `Statement` by [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) then. See also [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) how to use prepared statement.

Comment: THANKS A MILLION IT WORKS AND I AM SO BLOODY DUMB AND YOU ARE BRILLIANT AND MY SAVIOR!!! Thank you for the fast reply!

Comment: yeah, at first I thought that the *compilation error is weird but when I google it, i found someone having the same problem and another someone mentioned about ResultSet blah blah blah which I don't really get it. None of my data that I want to insert is an integer. So when you mentioned that executeUpdate doesnt return a resultset and you said 'just ignore it', I tried deleting off the resultset and it works! haha